# Use a variable value as a part of array name

Tags: c#, arrays

I've read other similar Questions. But, All of them use `bash`. IDK anything about that language.
The Thing I want to do is:

```
int i=0;   //Value of i will change as I want to use it in loop
string name="c"+i;
double a= name[i]; //The real name of arrays I have declared are: c0[],c1[] etc
```

It gives error: **"Project" does not contain a definition for "name"**
So, How do I acheive this?

Comment: You have declared the name as the string and tried to use it as the array. How could it possible? Explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want the first element within the variable `myVariable1`, so effectivly `myVariable1[1]`, or just the value of `myVariable1` (assuming `i` is one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you have a set of variables, all sharing a common name, e.g. `MyVariable1`, `MyVariable2`, etc.

Instead of having so many similar variables, you should use an array, or in your case an array of arrays:

```
var myVariableArray = new double[][] { c[0], c[1], ... };
```

Now you can easily acces the i-th number within that array:

```
double a = myVariableArray[i][i];
```

Alternativly if those variables actually are *members* (fields or propertiers) within your class, you can also use reflection to get the right member from a string:

```
var fields = typeof(MyType).GetField(name + i);
double b[];
if(field != null)
    b = (double[]) field.GetValue(instanceOfMyType, null);
else
{
    var prop = typeof(MyType).GetProperty(name + i);
    if(prop != null)
        b = (double[]) prop.GetValue(instanceOfMyType, null);
}
a = b[i];
```

However such a data-structure is bad design, you should go with an array (or list) of members, instead of having dozens of similar members.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of arrays (two-dimensional arrays), don't you?

To create an array of arrays, do this:

```
double[][] twoDArray = new double[][x];
```

where `x` is the number of arrays you want.

Now you can populate it with some arrays like this:

```
twoDArray[0] = new double[] {1.0, 1.1, 1.2};
twoDArray[1] = new double[] {7.7, 8.8, 9.9};
```

To access an array in the 2D array, you don't even need `name`, you just use `i` directly!

```
double[] oneOfTheArrays = twoDArray[i];
double a = oneOfTheArray[0];
```

Or more simply:

```
double a = twoDArray[i][0];
```